# How to loop through two lists & add conditional statement to execute something when one condition is true

Tags: json, list, loops, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a question, i got the sid list & the DB open_mode, i am trying to run a sql script on the DB when below two conditions satisfy:

1. DB name should end with '1'.
2. DB Open_Mode should be 'READ WRITE'.

i am using ansible dynamic inventory to get the sid's from the host & loop through that list, but i am unable to use the two conditions to work through the conditions i am adding.

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  strategy: free
  tasks:
  - include_vars: roles/oracle/vars/install_vars.yaml
    vars:
     var_list:
        - script_name

  - set_fact:
      ORACLE_HOMES_DIR: "/u01/app/oracle/product"
      DB_HOME: "{{ ORACLE_HOMES_DIR }}/{{ ORACLE_VERSION }}/dbinst_1"

  - name: Copy script to host
    copy:
      src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/{{ script_name }}"
      dest: "/tmp/"
      owner: "{{ USER_ORACLE }}"
      group: "{{ GROUP_ORACLE }}"
      mode: 0755

  - name: Verify if the DB is open READ WRITE (or) not
    become_user: "{{ USER_ORACLE }}"
    environment:
      ORACLE_SID: "{{ sid }}"
      ORACLE_HOME: "{{ ORACLE_HOME }}"
    shell: "echo \"set pagesize 0\n select trim(open_mode) from v\\$database;\" | {{ORACLE_HOME}}/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba"
    with_items: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['sid_list'] }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: sid
    register: om

  - name: Get list of sid that are open in READ WRITE mode
    set_fact:
      sid_list: "{{ om.results | selectattr('sid','search','1$') | map (attribute='sid') | list }}"

  - name: Get the OPEN MODE output of the sid's from the list
    set_fact:
      om_out: "{{ om.results | selectattr('stdout') | map (attribute='stdout') | list }}"

  - name: execute sql script
    become_user: "{{ USER_ORACLE }}"
    environment:
      ORACLE_SID: "{{ item.0 }}"
      ORACLE_HOME: "{{ ORACLE_HOME }}"
    shell: "{{ ORACLE_HOME }}/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba @/tmp/{{ script_name }}"
    when: item.1 == 'READ WRITE'
    with_together:
      - "{{ sid_list }}"
      - "{{ om_out }}"
```

I am expected the playbook to execute the SQL script on the DB, but i am getting error saying "conditional result was False"

```
TASK [Get list of sid that are open in READ WRITE mode] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /uhome/abhi/ansible/sql_script_execute.yaml:44
ok: [dwracdb1] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "sid_list": [
            "abhitest1",
            "dw1"
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [Get the SQL output from all the sid's] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /uhome/abhi/ansible/sql_script_execute.yaml:48
ok: [dwracdb1] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "om_out": [
            "READ WRITE",
            "READ WRITE"
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [Print om out] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /uhome/abhi/ansible/sql_script_execute.yaml:52
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item=[u'abhitest1', u'READ WRITE']) => {
    "msg": "sid output is abhitest1 om output is READ WRITE"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item=[u'dw1', u'READ WRITE']) => {
    "msg": "sid output is dw1 om output is READ WRITE"
}

TASK [execute sql script] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /uhome/abhi/ansible/sql_script_execute.yaml:61
fatal: [dwracdb1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The conditional check 'item.1 == 'READ WRITE'' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.1 == 'READ WRITE'): 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/uhome/abhi/ansible/sql_script_execute.yaml': line 61, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: execute sql script\n    ^ here\n"
}
```

Comment: Would you update your question to include the output of the `debug` task that prints `sid output is {{ sid_list }} om output is {{ om_out }}`?

Comment: hi Larsks, here is the output:

TASK [Print om out] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /uhome/airukulla/ansible/sql_script_execute.yaml:51
ok: [dwracdb1.qai.expertcity.com] => {
    "msg": "sid output is [u'abhitest1', u'dw1'] om output is [u'READ WRITE', u'READ WRITE']"
}

Comment: Generally, when people ask for additional information you should **update the question** rather than leaving a comment (because it's not possible to properly format code samples, etc, in comments).

Comment: Based on your debug output, `om_out` is a list `["READ WRITE", "READ WRITE"]`, so of course your conditional `om_out == 'READ WRITE'` fails.

Comment: ok, so any suggestions how to recode my playbook so it works as i am expected? Any suggestions (or) ideas?

Comment: I am quite very new to posting questions in stakoverflow, so wasn't sure how to do that.

Comment: Hi larsks, i have updated my code a bit. I will update it to my question, may be it will need better tuning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a formatting hint: move the `when` condition on your `block` up to the top so that it's obvious what it controls.  When you put it at the bottom it's not obvious:

```
- block:
  when:
    - hostvars[inventory_hostname]['sid_list'] is defined
```

In this task, you're collecting multiple results (one for each entry in `sid_list`):

```
- name: Verify if the DB is open READ WRITE (or) not
  become_user: "{{ USER_ORACLE }}"
  environment:
    ORACLE_SID: "{{ sid }}"
    ORACLE_HOME: "{{ ORACLE_HOME }}"
  shell: "echo \"set pagesize 0\n select trim(open_mode) from v\\$database;\" | {{ORACLE_HOME}}/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba"
  with_items: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['sid_list'] }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: sid
  register: om

- name: Get list of sid that are open in READ WRITE mode
  set_fact:
    sid_list: "{{ om.results | selectattr('sid','search','1$') | map (attribute='sid') | list }}"
```

That's why, when you run this task, you end up with a list of results:

```
- name: Get the SQL output from all the sid's
  set_fact:
    om_out: "{{ om.results | selectattr(\"stdout\",'equalto','READ WRITE') | map (attribute='stdout') | list }}"
```

You're doing the correct thing here in your `debug` task using `with_together`: you need that in order to associate a result in `om_out` with one of the entries in `sid_list`:

```
- name: Print om out
  debug:
   msg: sid output is {{ item.0 }} om output is {{ item.1 }}
  with_together:
    - "{{ sid_list }}"
    - "{{ om_out }}"
```

You should do the same thing when trying to execute your sql script.  Get rid of the `block`, because you only have a single task and you can't `loop` a block:

```
  - name: execute sql script
    become_user: "{{ USER_ORACLE }}"
    environment:
      ORACLE_SID: "{{ sid.0 }}"
      ORACLE_HOME: "{{ ORACLE_HOME }}"
    shell: "{{ ORACLE_HOME }}/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba @/tmp/{{ script_name }}"
    when:
      - sid.1 == 'READ WRITE'
    with_together:
      - "{{ sid_list }}"
      - "{{ om_out }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: sid
```

In this loop, `sid.0` will be the value from `sid_list`, and `sid.1` will be the corresponding value from `om_out`.

Comment: (caveat: I know nothing about oracle)

Comment: Hi larsks, i am still seeing error here:

```
TASK [execute sql script] 
FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The conditional check 'item.1 == 'READ WRITE'' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.1 == 'READ WRITE'): 'item' is undefined\n\n
```

Comment: You're getting that error because you've set `loop_var: sid`.  Replace `item` with `sid` in the task, or just get rid of `loop_var`.  I've fixed the task in the answer.

Comment: Thanks larsks, i have edited and confirm everything works now. I have updated my full code which works in my Question.

Comment: hi Larsks, after using the updates code, i see the playbook keep running something in loop and it never returns the command prompt. Any suggestions how we can break it with any condition?

Comment: Also here my ansible & python version:

```
ansible 2.7.10
  config file = None
  configured module search path = [u'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ara/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /uhome/airukulla/abhiansible/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /uhome/airukulla/abhiansible/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jul 13 2018, 13:06:57) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]
```